# Is there a way to create/edit a theme in Android from Java?

Tags: java, android, user-interface, dynamic, themes

I was wondering if anyone knows how to create/edit themes in Android from Java? I am already aware of all possible ways of coloring views and creating custom views, but I need specifically to change or create a new app theme from code. Any hint would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately the only way to do it was the `ReflectionAPI` from Java's `reflection` package. Not a good solution, but the only one that worked.

Answer (score 0):

Unless if the views have methods for changing colors, attributes, etc you may be limited to having multiple themes for specific views and switching them programmatically throughout run time.

Comment: Google seems to be creating themes internally, I would prefer a solution like that. Unfortunately nobody is interested in making this process public, so I guess I'm stuck with coloring drawables..